# c++ error when installing package in R

Tags: r, ubuntu

I cannot install any errors any more when installing a package in RStudio in Ubuntu.
The error I receive is

> checking for g++... g++
>   checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/tmp/RtmpSkung5/R.INSTALL70592285d1c6/nloptr':
>   configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
>   See`config.log' for more details

Things I already tried
- install g++
- install cpp
- Try to look into config.log but I don't find this file anywhere.

Any idea how to proceed?

Thanks

Comment: `config.log` should be in `/tmp/RtmpSkung5/R.INSTALL70592285d1c6/nloptr/build`. You need to look at that and post the relevant error messages.

Comment: How is this Rstudio related question?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik is it related as he is using it and he is a beginer.

Comment: The dir  /tmp/RtmpSkung5/R.INSTALL70592285d1c6/nloptr/build  does not exist. Not even the  /tmp/RtmpSkung5 directory.

Comment: it seems that R expects a different compiler version and the system has as 
default, what is the output of this `g++ /etc/R/Makeconf`

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel The output is g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
compilation terminated.

Comment: what kind of machine are you using?64 or 32?and what version of ubuntu?

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64. dell latitude 6430u 8MB RAM, intel i5. BTW already thanks for the effort.

Comment: oh!i just posted a clue to solution,,let me delete it then if you solved it,,and i think you should post your solution ,,happy coding ;)